# How to add an NSTextView with changing height inside an NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview, nstextfield, nstextview

I have an NSTextView inside an NSTableView. I would like the NSTextView to be editable in such a way that when I add content to it, the NSTableView  and NSTableCellView resizes to show the full content of the NSTextView.

Example of this behaviour from Omnifocus

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to use NSTableView's [noteHeightOfRowChangedWithIndexes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableview/1532126-noteheightofrowswithindexeschang?language=objc) along with [controlTextdidChange](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1428982-controltextdidchange) in order to achieve the desired effect.